# Using described_class when including a module under test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing some rspec's to test some modules correctly implement their behaviour.

The module looks like this:

```
module Under::Test
  def some_behaviour
  end
end
```

I can't do this in RSpec:

```
describe Under::Test do
  subject {Class.new{include described_class}.new}
```

At the point `#described_class` is called, it can no longer be resolved because self is an instance of Class, which doesn't have a #describe_class method. So I am forced to repeat myself:

```
subject {Class.new{include Under::Test}.new}
```

Or use it in the spec in a different way to how it's used by my clients:

```
subject {Object.new.extend described_class}
```

This has the same end effect, but something in me thinks that if I'm asking my clients to `include Under::Test`, then the tests should look as close to how it's used by them as possible.

I can use the closure property to fix this, but I wonder if it's no better. Does this have code smell?

```
describe Under::Test do
  subject {mudule = described_class;Class.new{include mudule}.new}

  it 'has some behaviour' do
    expect(subject.some_behaviour).to be
  end
end
```

Note, I also asked in r/ruby on reddit, someone there suggested:

```
subject {Class.new.include(described_class).new}
```

which might be how I go.

Comment: I prefer to simply repeat the module name. The use of a local variable (`mudule`) is a clever way to avoid the duplication, but I think clarity is more important that DRY-ness, especially in a spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your eventual aim is to `include` the current `described_class` module in a newly created `Class`, how about the following workaround?

```
RSpec.describe NewModule do
  let(:test_class) do
    Class.new.tap do |klass|
      klass.include(described_class)
    end
  end

  specify do
    expect(test_class.ancestors).to include described_class # passes
  end
end
```

And here's an example of including the module's methods in an object:

```
module NewModule
  def identity
    itself
  end
end

RSpec.describe NewModule do
  let(:one) do
    1.tap do |obj|
      obj.class.include(described_class)
    end
  end

  specify do
    expect(one.identity).to eq 1 # passes
  end
end
```

Note that the `include` method for a `Class` isn't `private` in Ruby v2+. If you're using an older version, you have to use `klass_name.send(:include, described_class)`

Comment: thanx @Humza - that public #include tip also came out in the same discussion on reddit

Answer (score 3):

I think both of your solutions are just fine, I like a little bit more

```
Object.new.extend described_class
```

for its readability and conciseness. If you want to use `Class.new` approach I think it's ok to repeat module name, as Jared said, readability is more important here than dryness.